# Having trouble while installing composer on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, curl, composer-php

I've just installed apache, php and curl to my computer. But I think there is something wrong with cURL with Php5.6. Actually I can install composer with ignoring the warnings but I will not be able to use composer then.

I get this:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

When I run this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Peace..

Comment: I also had a problem today with PHP 5.6 related to SwiftMailer and SSL certificates. I just rolled back to 5.5.

Comment: How to roll back to 5.5?

Comment: I am on Kububtu 14.04. To get PHP 5.6 I installed a ppa, then upgraded everything. To rollback, I removed the ppa, uninstalled PHP, then reinstalled all the php components (php5-fpm, php-xdebug, php5-common, php5-mysql, php5-mcrypt) from the official repositories to get back to 5.5.

Comment: Have you tried using php like mentioned in documentation - https://getcomposer.org/download? `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php` Also you can download composer manually from: https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

Comment: @TomášVotruba Manually fetching Composer will work, but as he pointed out, he will run into the same problem, when fetching packages then.

Comment: @TomášVotruba PHP Warning:  readfile(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1

Comment: @TomášVotruba the problem is not just about installing composer but with curl doesn't work I also can not use composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your local certificates:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

or

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs
sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

And then use this cert file on the command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

All in all: your pull new certs and use this on the cURL command on the CLI.

---

The next step is to get the cURL PHP extension working.

- adjust `php.ini`
- enable openssl extension
- enable curl extension
- `curl.cainfo=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`
- `openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

Comment: At least you have updated your certificates, now try running `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

Comment: A. Kock still doesn't work. (But I already had composer installed so I can use composer require command now without errors)

Comment: I don't understand. Is the problem resolved? Else: Do you have all needed packages installed? And please post the output of `curl -v`. We need to check the certificate location.

Comment: A. Kock curl: "no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information"